# How do I convert my old v0.13 node to a v0.14 pruned node when I already have the full 65gb downloaded?

Tags: monerod-commands, ubuntu

I run `monerod` via the Ubuntu command line. I'm on v0.13 and I want to prune my Monero node's database and take advantage of the v0.14 features. How can I do this? What command do I need to type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to v0.14.x and after you have upgraded and run, the database will be migrated to the latest version. You can then exit the daemon and run `monero-blockchain-prune`, which will prune the database.

Note that pruning is not scheduled for release until 0.14.0.**1**.

Comment: Will this make scanning for my updated balance faster?

Comment: From my understanding, no.